# How to unzip .tar.gz file in apache beam java sdk

Tags: java, compression, apache-beam, apache-commons, minio

In my apache beam pipeline i am getting a file of format .tar.gz and i want to uncompress the tar file and save it's content to minio cloud. I am using following way to uncompress file but though this i am able to store it on local storage but it wont work for storing it to minio cloud i.e. play.min.io and i am using apache common compress to untar.

```
         @DoFn.ProcessElement
         public void processElement(@Element ReadableFile element, Void) throws IOException {
             InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(element.open());
             TarArchiveInputStream tis = new TarArchiveInputStream(is);
             File destFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Compressed\\unzip");
                if(!destFile.exists()){
                     destFile.mkdir();
                }
                TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = null;
                while ((tarEntry = tis.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                    File outputFile = new File(destFile + File.separator + tarEntry.getName());

                    if(tarEntry.isDirectory()){

                        if(!outputFile.exists()){
                            outputFile.mkdirs();
                        }
                    }else{
                        outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
                        IOUtils.copy(tis, fos);
                        fos.close();
                    }   
                }
                tis.close();
     }
     }
```

pipeline

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        Pipeline pipeline=Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection files=pipeline.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Compressed\\Ziped.tar.gz"))
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(Compression.GZIP));
        files.apply(ParDo.of(new unzip()));
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

When storing files on minio it uses object storage but this code produce a output stream. Can any one help me with the code.
Thanks in advance